# Pin Application to Specific Screen

Tags: display, window-manager

Is there anyway to pin windows that an application launches to a specific screen? As an example zoom launches two windows when starting a meeting one that for video and one with meeting information. It used to keep launching them in the same screens but lately I have noticed that each window will open on a different screen each time. The pattern seems random as sometimes they will just swap places but other times they will go to a different screen where it is not normally on to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Apps will launch to a given Space, if set - right click the app in the Dock > Options , *.
They will only launch to a given physical display if you don't have "Displays have separate Spaces" on in System prefs > Mission Control.

Apps do not like being spread across multiple Spaces.

*Apple use the terms Desktop and Space interchangeably, unfortunately. Display, however, always means 'physical screen'.

Comment: This isn't from the app itself launching but from something happening after the app itself is already running. In my case I keep zoom running as I will use it for meetings throughout the day. My first meeting could launch the windows in the correct order on screens 1 and 2 but the second meeting could swap them or change one of them to screen 3. Zoom my default will always launch the video and meeting stats on different windows.

Comment: Have you checked if you have "Displays have separate Spaces"  on or off? This will only work if it's off.

Comment: It is currently on and I will have to look into that option more.

Comment: It's quite a paradigm shift, but at the moment you are trying to force an app to use three different Spaces - it's not going to like doing that.

Comment: I am not trying to force the application to do anything other than open the same window every time. Zoom (the application in question) opens multiple windows in different spaces whenever you start or join a meeting, in fact it opens them up in full screen mode. All I am looking to do is to determine if I can get them to open up in the same spaces every time so I don't have to rearrange windows so I can get them to the correct places so I can work properly.

Comment: fullscreen windows each generate their own, un-numbered Space, so I doubt you're going to get any control over them. [Yet one more reason I absolutely never use fullscreen; one of the worst thought-out 'improvements' Apple ever made, imnsho] Fullscreen basically is designed for single-screen laptops. It's a mess on anything more sophisticated.